# Why I can not declare a variable inside an ES6 class by using let, const or var keyword but I can declare it directly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, ecmascript-6, es6-class

For the following code I wanted to know the reason behind this behavior in an ES6 Class:

```
class One {
    //why the following code is not allowed.
    let check = false; 
    const PI = 3.14;   
    var v = 'Hello';    

    //why the following code is allowed.
    chk = false;       
    Pi = 3.14;         
    vv = "Hi";         
}
```

I know I can write code like below but I wanted to know the real reason behind the above code.

```
class Sample {
   constructor(x, y) {
      this.x= x;
      this.y= y;
   }
}
```

Comment: Variables are not the same as properties. As such it would only be confusing to have the syntax of class fields use `var`, `let` or `const`.

Answer (score 4):

```
class One {
    //why the following code is not allowed.
    let check = false; 
    const PI = 3.14;   
    var v = 'Hello';    

    //why the following code is allowed.
    chk = false;       
    Pi = 3.14;         
    vv = "Hi";         
}
```

Actually, neither of those is legal javascript currently. The latter is an example of class fields, which is currently a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), so it will eventually be legal syntax. With a [transpiler](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties), you can use that syntax right now and the transpiler will move the code into the constructor.

```
class One {
  chk = false;       
  Pi = 3.14;         
  vv = "Hi";         
}
```

Becomes roughly:

```
class One {
  constructor() {
    this.chk = false;       
    this.Pi = 3.14;         
    this.vv = "Hi";         
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The trivial answer is "because that's how the [*class*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) syntax is (currently) defined".

Class declarations are basically a bunch of shorthand function declarations (they just drop the "function" keyword), you can't put executable statements outside of the methods (except for proposed [public and private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields), but they aren't in ECMA-262 yet) e.g.

```
class Foo {

  // shorthand function declaration of mandatory constructor method
  constructor (...) {
    // Usual function syntax in here
  }

  // shorthand function declaration of class method
  blah (...) {
    // Usual function syntax in here
  }

  // shorthand function declaration of static method
  static bar (...) {  
    // Usual function syntax in here
  }

  // etc.
}
```

There are ways to implement private members ([JavaScript - Private members explanation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174500/javascript-private-members-explanation)) but I think it goes away from the class syntax.